# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model' TastyPie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I keep getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 217, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 459, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1299, in get_list
    objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2113, in obj_get_list
    return self.authorized_read_list(objects, bundle)

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 610, in authorized_read_list
    auth_result = self._meta.authorization.read_list(object_list, bundle)

  File "/srv/www/poka/app/env/main/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/authorization.py", line 151, in read_list
    klass = self.base_checks(bundle.request, object_list.model)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

This happens when I am calling the following model:

```
class NewsResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:

        queryset = News.objects.select_related('picture').all()
        allowed_methods = ['get','patch']
        include_resource_uri = False
        include_absolute_url = False
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to demonstrate your error:

```
>>> object_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> object_list.model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

I suspect that `object_list` in your case is a list and thus does not have attribute `model`. Please check your code.

Comment: So.. I've spotted that in my function def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):, I return [] if it doesn't have my custom filters. As a result, when Tastypie does a .model on my [], it can't find a model. How could I fix this?

Comment: So does `apply_filters()` always return a list? When there is no custom filters, it returns `[]`. What does it return otherwise?

Comment: Returns a list, but there is a "model" objet attached to it. So I just need to do: News.objects.none() instead of [].

Comment: You need to redesign you code to check for empty list.

Answer (score 1):

As Hai vu said, your object has no `model` attribute.

To help you understand your problem, you can use PDB to debug this.
This is very simple to set.
Just before the line responsible of the problem, write this in your code:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

It will freeze your server as this point in the code.
Then in the shell, feel free to test things like :

```
list.model # will throw the same error
```

or

```
list.__dict__ # will show all the possible attributes that you can use with the list object
```